# Part of pthread stack seems to be already used

Tags: stack, pthreads

I've set the stack size of a pthread in Linux to 16 KB. If I then push an array bigger than 8 KB on the stack, the applications stops with a segmentation fault. It seems to me that I am trying to access memory below the bottom of the stack, which is probably unmapped memory and hence the segfault.

Here is the sample code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

void *start_routine(void *arg)
{
  size_t size = 9*1024;
  unsigned char arr[size];

  memset(arr, 0, size);
}

int main()
{
  int err;
  pthread_attr_t threadAttr;
  size_t stacksize;
  void *stackAddr;
  pthread_t thread;

  pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);
  pthread_attr_setstacksize(&threadAttr, 16*1024);
  pthread_attr_getstacksize(&threadAttr, &stacksize);
  printf("stacksize: %d\n", stacksize);

  pthread_create(&thread, &threadAttr, start_routine, NULL );
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

It seems strange that I loose around 8 KB of stack. I tried also with slightly bigger stack sizes. Somehow it seems to vary how much of the stack I can use.

I know that for nowadays-systems (except some embedded systems) these few bytes are not really important but I'm just curious why I cannot use most of the defined stack. I do not expect that I can use the whole stack, but loosing around 8 KB seems quite much.

What information is there put on the thread's stack before the entry-routine is called?

Thanks
Philip

Comment: I compile and run the program without problems using gcc on MacOS.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you can check that the return val of pthread_attr_setstacksize(...) == 0. The man page says it returns -1 and sets errno to EINVAL if you try to set the stack size above some system-imposed limit. That seems kind of unlikely though.

Comment: Have a look at the output of `ulimit -s` - you probably not getting whole 16K per thread.

Comment: @Kevin Interesting to know that you can run the program on MacOS. Maybe you can try to increase the size of the array and see how far you can get?

Comment: @Kevin The pthread_attr_setstacksize-function returns 0. And additionally I have the request of the stacksize with pthread_attr_getstacksize. This seems to be fine.

Comment: @Nikolai Output of `ulimit -s` is 8192K. That's the maximum allowed stack size of 8 MB per thread - and 8 MB should be enough in this case J. Setting it to another value doesn't change anything - which doesn't surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation in the glibc nptl source code I come to the conclusion that at the bottom of the stack there is put the pthread-struct of the thread who owns the stack and likely some other variables depending on the glibc-configuration. They use together around 3K. The top of the stack is filled with a guard page, which is typically 4K big. Thus around 7-8K are already used. I am a bit surprised that at least the memory for the guard page is not allocated separately. On the top of my head I thought to remember that that would be the case but it isn't.